# View Subscribing to Property of an instance object in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to subscribe to the Property of an instance object in ViewModel rather than a Property in viewModel itself.

```
class MainViewModel
{
  #region Fields
  private ModularViewModel modularViewModel1;
  #end region
}
```

The main Viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and so as the instance ViewModel.

Is it possible to subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged event of a Property in modularViewModel from the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just use the `.` syntax to traverse your data structure.

So in your case:

```
"{Binding Path=modularViewModel1.SomeProperty}"
```

Remember that all properties used for binding must be `public` (your sample is `private`, and a field, not a property).

The binding will subscribe to the correct `PropertyChanged` event automatically in this case.